# Чи існує слово "шукомий"?

Tags: вживання-слів, прикметники

Знайомий ужив слово ***шукомий*** в контексті *«той, який треба знайти»*.

На перший погляд, слово звучить цілком по-українськи (за аналогією із ***питомий***), втім, СУМ не містить такого прикметника.

Натомість, пропонується ***шуканий***.

> [ШУ́КАНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/shukanyj), а, е.
>
> 1. Дієпр. пас. мин. ч. до шукати.
> 2. у знач. прикм. Якого шукають, потрібно знайти, розшукати. *Шуканий хліб гарний молодикові* (Ганна Барвінок, Опов.., 1902, 148).
> 3. у знач. прикм., мат. Який повинен бути визначений, встановлений. *Рівняння, що зв'язує незалежну змінну і шукану функцію, називають
>      інтегралом диференціального рівняння (Курс математичного аналізу*, II,
>      1956, 226); Шукана величина; Шукане число;  //  у знач. ім. шукане,
>      ного, сер. Величина, яка має бути визначена, встановлена.

[Пошук у Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57.3459j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) пропонує усього 6 випадків вживання ***шукомий***.

**Тож чи можна вважати, що слово *шукомий* все ж існує в українській мові, чи варто уникати його вживання?**

Comment: Була дискусія в кількох інших гілках.... Слово починає існувати в той момент, коли його вжили, а не тоді, коли якісь люди в Києві вирішили додати слово до словника. Але якщо дивитися по аналогії, то вжите слово мало б мати трохи інше значення. Вагомий - "має вагу постійно", а не "повинен мати вагу", знайомий - "кого знають", а не "повинні знати". Шукомий - (по відчуттях і аналогії) це той, кого/що постійно шукають. Тобто можливо любов у значенні "другої половинки" може бути шукомою, "золото Полуботка" може бути шукомим... Потрібне ціле речення, щоб зрозуміти в якому значенні слово вжилося.

Comment: Можливо по цій темі потрібно шукати словотворення прикметників за допомогою суфікса -ом. Здається колись бачив, але тепер натрапляю тільки на прислівниковий суфікс -ом, який в давнину був закінченням (тишкОМ, гуртОМ...)

Comment: Оу! Згадав де бачив! Це було в розділі не про прикметники, а про дієприкметники. Як відомо традиційна україністика не визнає дієприкметників теперішнього часу, але ті форми, які зараз існують, вважаються не дієприкметниками, а віддієслівними прикметниками, що позначають не дію, а ПОСТІЙНУ ознаку. Отже шукомий - той кого постійно шукають і слово цілком відповідає нормам української мови. (якщо хто найде потрібне посилання, можна оформити як відповідь.)

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо Можете взяти тут http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/diyeprykmetnyky

"...зрідка трапляються віддієслівні прикметники з суфіксами -им- (невгасима любов), -ом- (невідомий чоловік), що також утратили ознаки дії й набули постійної якості."

і оформити як відповідь.

Від мене буде +1. :)

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо, контекст був *шукоме значення (Excel)*. І якщо оформите відповідь, як радить Kyrylo Yatsenko, від мене, без сумніву, теж +1 :)

Comment: Надто скидається на кальку з рос. «искомый». Попри існування тут гурту прихильників суфіксу -ом, це не найтиповіший словотвірний засіб української мови.

Answer (score 5):

Візьмемо правила словотворення для відносних прикметників.

[Сучасна українська мова: Підручник / О.Д. Пономарів](http://filologukraine.ucoz.ua/publ/mova/sulm/slovotvorennja_prikmetnikiv/3-1-0-58),
В.В. Різун, Л.Ю. Шевченко та ін.; за ред. О.Д. Пономарева. -
4-те вид. - К.: Либідь, 2008. - 488 с.

Є іменник *пошук* і існує відносний прикметник [*пошуковий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/poshukovyj), який утворюється з допомогою суфікса `-ов`.

Але, на жаль, [**немає**](http://filologukraine.ucoz.ua/publ/mova/sulm/slovotvorennja_prikmetnikiv/3-1-0-58) словотворення прикметників з допомогою суфікса `-ом`. Принаймні, я ніде його не знайшов. Проте є [корінь `шук`](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA) і відповідний прикметник на `-ан` - [*шуканий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/shukanyj)

Слова [*питомий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pytomyj) та *питання* навряд однокореневі з коренем `пит`.

Answer (score 2):

Наросток ***-ом-*** і також близькі до його ***-ен-*** і ***-им-*** [створюють](https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/bitstream/6789/3462/1/IUM_dovidnyk.pdf#page=310)<sup>1</sup> пасивний дїєприкметник теперїшнього часу: *нєсомъ*, *зна~мъ*, *гонимъ*.

Існуїть навіть [думка](https://ena.lpnu.ua:8443/server/api/core/bitstreams/b9de6ea1-212a-4647-a6fc-63dc947085b1/content)<sup>2</sup> замінити чинні на такі, де є сенс.

> Історично дієприкметниковий суфікс ***-ом-*** здавна виступає словотворчим засобом в українських прикметниках, порівн.: ***відо́мий**, **пито́мий**, **знайо́мий**, **свідо́мий**, **блиго́мий*** “близький”, ***ваго́мий**, **їдо́мий*** “їстівний”, ***знико́мий*** (рос. ***исчезающий***), зрештою, ***рухо́мий***. Як бачимо, рідковживаним цього суфікса не назвеш, тим часом за його допомогою, керуючись знову ж таки аналогією, можна утворити семантично прозорі, легкозрозумілі назви дійових ознак, як-от: ***біго́ма** хвиля*, *мішень* — рос. ***бегущая** волна*, *мишень* — замість пропонованих у новітніх словниках ***біжна́***, ***бігу́ча*** або ще якось. Власне кажучи, ***бігу́ча*** — це прикметник якісний, на зразок: ***тягу́ча** пісня* (бо інша може бути ще тягучіша), ***несу́ча** курка* (ще якась може нести більше яєць), ***везу́чий** віл* (у власне-українському значенні “здатний добре везти”: *старий віл, та ще везучий*). У нашому ж випадку потрібен відносний прикметник.
>
> Функцію, аналогічну до ***-ом-***, в українській мові виконує суфікс ***-им-***, порівн.: ***види́ма** смерть* “неминуча очевидна смерть”, *іти на **види́мий** ро́змир* “цілеспрямовано йти на конфлікт”, ***нещади́мий*** “нічого не вартий, ні до чого не придатний” (*голь нещадима* — рос. *голь перекатная*), ***пити́мий*** “питний” тощо. Попри їхню генетичну дієприкметниковість, народна мова вживає цих суфіксів виключно в прикметниках — подібно до теж історично дієприкметникових ***-уч*** (***-юч***), ***-ач*** (***-яч***), ***-ущ*** (***-ющ***), ***-ащ*** (***-ящ***).

Тому ***шукомий*** це радше *той, якого можна знайти*, а не *треба*, шчо зазвичай підсилюють дїєсловами, нп. *знайдїть*. Однак і тому в більшостї випадків *шуканий* доречнїший. Порівняй: *знайомий* — той, кого можуть знати, *знаний* — той кого знають, тобто *відомий*, той кого можуть [відати](//academia.edu/88239113/_Knowing_How_in_Slovene_Treading_the_Other_Path)<sup>3</sup>.

Там ж і згадано про *невиправданий пріоритет у відносних прикметниках суфікса*  ***-ов-***:

> Назагал, суфікс ***-ов-*** (***-ев-***, ***-єв-***) може придатися там, де вкрай потрібно розвести якісний і відносний прикметники, як-от: ***серде́чний*** “щирий” і ***серде́шний*** “нещасний” (якісні) — ***серце́вий*** “повʼязаний із серцем” (відносний), ***коне́чний*** “необхідний” (якісний) — ***кінце́вий*** “що на кінці” (відносний). Але яка нагальна потреба від, приміром, ***лави́на*** творити прикметник ***лавино́вий***, коли давно функціонує, модель ***рослина*** > ***рослинний***, ***картина*** > ***картинний***, ***машина*** > ***машинний***? Приклад виправданого вжиття цього суфікса: ***причина*** > ***причино́вий** зв'язок*, бо ***причи́нний*** — це “божевільний”.

Тому *пошуковий* належить гиншій катеґорії, про шчо вже було зазначено там ж: *відносний прикметник*.

---

Нотатки

1. Історія української мови: словник-довідник / ідея, упорядкування та
   окремі статті В. В. Денисюка. – Умань : Візаві, 2013. – 387 с.
2. Словотвірні негаразди новітнього термінотворення / Іван Борисюк, 2000
   Інститут української мови НАН України, Київ
3. ‘Knowing How’ in Slovene: Treading the Other Path / Barbara Sonnenhauser